# BLDC Motor Driver: Justifying better design approach

Tags: mosfet, brushless-dc-motor, circuit-design

When and why it is better for a design engineer to design a BLDC driving circuit using individual MOSFETs, instead of selecting a ready made driving IC to simplify the design?

*Here I just do not mean to run a BLDC but also control its different parameters. For instance: Speed; which can be controlled using a potentiometer but programming seems more practical in certain cases.*

Comment: Usually, because the current or voltage level is too high for available ICs.  Potentially, because they got a comparably good deal on cheap discretes which holds up even after assembly cost, or need nuances of behavior or degrees of performance not provided by available ICs.  It's not immediately clear that there are a lot of applications larger than a cooling fan/CD ROM/ultamicro RC plane where IC drivers make sense, and even the latter often use discrete SOT23 FETs.

Comment: Then why manufacturers do not design ICs capable of bearing high current?

Comment: They do up to a point, and they stop at the point where doing so becomes impractical - you may for example see the occasional few-amps class BLDC driver using a bunch of H-bridge ICs rather than discrete FETs.  But discrete FETs each with its own heatsink interface will always be more capable, as the power density per unit heatsink connection area lower (and that includes little packages that shed their heat to the surrounding air - individual packages have more surface area).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of the most important points is power handling

using individual MOSFETS will give you a very wide range for how much power it can give you

for example
if your BLDC require 30 or even 50 amps to reach its max power(torque and speed) I think it will be hard to find off-the-shelf integrated circuit that can support this amount of power, usually at this case there is no escape from using individual transistors to handle this power

also heat dissipation is a big problem you must handle in your design

in case of using ind. Trans. it would be much easier to distribute the heat over multiple packages instead of one package which would be in the other case the IC

one disadvantage is the size of the final design

sometimes you need the minimal amount of components in your design, but if you will use multiple MOSFET approach you will definitely need a controller also (microcontroller as an example)

Comment: To drive BLDC according to one's requirements, having an MCU in design is inescapable. The case is just not to let BLDC run, but let it be controlled too.

Comment: No more answers, so your answer seems good so far. I accepted it. Thanks.